# Compare and select the first non-null column value Python Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Only compare 3 columns, homePhone, workPhone,CellPhone,

how to select the first non null column value, in 'I want' column,

use Python Pandas

```
    name    homePhone   workPhone   CellPhone   I want
1   Tom        888        666         null       888
2   John      null        777        null       777
3   Lily      null       null       333         333
```

Answer (score -1):

If the matter indeed involves only three columns, you can use `np.where` from NumPy:

```
import numpy as np  
df['I want'] = np.where(df['homePhone'].isnull(), 
                        np.where(df['workPhone'].isnull(), 
                                 df['CellPhone'], 
                                 df['workPhone']), 
                        df['homePhone']).astype(int)
```